# Export and import data from PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I exported data with phpMyAdmin, but when I import the data I get this error:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

I can set the data accordingly and then I don't get the error. But is there a better way to do this? Something like disabling some options in phpMyAdmin or adding some query to SQL?

Comment: PMA used to do things like this all the time but it has got a lot better in recent times (in my experience). Basically the order of some operations in the export file is wrong. I would update PMA on both export and import servers and try again, you may find it disappears.

Comment: Could you try if it works when you check 'Enclose export in a transaction', 'Disable foreign key checks' and 'Extended inserts'?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is pma doesnt care about the order for the insert rows. so it happens a table-row is inserted with an FK where the FK row is not yet imported.

To solve this use the checkbox `Disable Foreign Key Checks` when exporting from PhpMyadmin. Or set it yourself:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and at the end:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

That error (`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`) is referenced in the [MySQL FK Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

To add a reference between 2 tables the condition must fit for existing data.

That means if you say `table1.id = table2.id` then all ids of `table1` and `table2` must match together.

To solve that you have to eliminate or fix those rows that don't match. 
Example:

```
table1.id  |  table2.fk
   1       |       1      ok 
   2       |     null     error
   3       |       4      error if id 4 is not in table1
```

Comment: good explanation of the error, but the outcome is wrong... its just pma doesnt care about the order of tables when generating the sql file.